# Para que servem esses sql modes no mysql?

Tags: mysql

Aqui esta o código:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Estão definindo flags ou configurações para as próximas queries que serão executadas. Geralmente são colocadas automaticamente durante a exportação do banco de dados para evitar incompatibilidade ou problemas em outras versões mais antigas do MySQL.